Why are some of the Terminid sectors in a 'Fog of War' state?
Some of the Terminid sectors have a 'Fog of War' effect:

If you zoom in on one of the sectors, you still don't see anything:

No other enemy factions have a similar effect. Why do some Terminid sectors have this 'Fog of War' effect?

It's called The Gloom.  There seems to be some lore about it, but what it actually means in game doesn't really seem to be known yet:

The Gloom is an interstellar Terminid spore cloud that encompasses several star systems. Though the purpose of the cloud is unknown, this unnatural phenomenon continuously grows, obscuring galactic map intelligence.


While its purpose is currently unknown to Super Earth scientists, its effects are felt as it obscures interstellar optics, reducing visibility to planets completely encompassed by it.

